# After export excel file from php, excel 2010 is not openning it

Tags: php, excel, mime-types

I have an script written in php that export a html table to excel using MIME types.

Since yesterday 2016/07/20, excel 2010 is not openning any more file from my web site and I notice that is not openning form any other web site that do the same exportation

This is a test code

```
<?php
header('ContentType : application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition : attachment;filename=test.xls');
header('Pragma : no-cache');

$out = "
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>something 1</td>
        <td>something 2</td>
        <td>something 3</td>
        <td>something 4</td>
        <td>something 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
";

echo $out;
?>
```

The code is still working but any excel 2010 is openning this file

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent (7/12/2016) MS Excel security update. Do the following to view the files in Excel:

1. Open an Excel sheet
2. Navigate to File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Protected View
3. Un-Check "Enable Protected View for file originating from the Internet".
4. Reopen the files.

I haven't found any permanent fix for this to continue to allow HTML->XLS viewing within Excel.

Comment: I've noticed this update but I thought was an windows update. I tried do something in excel trust center but without success. You save my day thank you your help work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I see from format of the file that it's .xls, which is from Excel 2003. There is a support issue in Microsoft site - here is [a link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2528682). Perhaps it's because of your Excel program, but not your site.